# Pulling Excel.xlsx workbook from Sharepoint site using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

As stated in the title, I've been trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to pull an Excel workbook from our company's Sharepoint site. I am able to retrieve the metadata for the file, but when I add the `/workbook/` segment to the URL, I receive the below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'workbook'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "bf41e41a-bc01-4c3b-b1d7-3125c4d48124",
      "date": "2019-04-10T16:29:07"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what the successful call getting the file metadata looks like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items/273
```

And here is the call I am making which returns the above error:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items/273/workbook/
```

I was able to find this stackoverflow post discussing a similar error, however that was a couple of years ago, apparently using a beta version of the Graph API, and I was not able to get any farther using suggestions from that post.
[Get workbook from sharepoint site using microsoft graph beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854660/get-workbook-from-sharepoint-site-using-microsoft-graph-beta)

I am building my request URL based on reading these two Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm using C# and building the requests with Restsharp.

Does anyone have any insight on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `/workbook` against a [`ListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0), it can only be used with a [`DriveItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

In order to do that, you'll need to first obtain the `DriveItem` associated with the `ListItem`:

```
/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items/273/driveitem/workbook
```

Comment: That works! Where did you go to learn that? The "Working with Excel in Microsoft Graph" doc doesn't specify that at all, and to my eyes indicates that a file could be accessed as I was attempting to.  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/excel?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I'm afraid it came years of experience being neck-deep in Graph metadata and nuances. That said, I completely agree: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4369

Comment: I get data for `/driveitem/` but for `/driveitem/workbook` I get  "innerError": {
                "code": "FileOpenNotFound",
                "message": "We couldn't find the file you wanted."
            }