# MS Graph API access to a workbook from a driveItem

Tags: node.js, excel, microsoft-graph-api

I have written some code which successfully accesses an excel spreadsheet on a sharepoint site. I did this by finding the driveid in graph explorer then browsed to find the workbook item and worksheet.

Now I need to do the same thing but I can't use Graph Explorer to find the drive ID so I understood that I could generate the drive id using the method shown at https://www.techmikael.com/2018/07/using-microsoft-graph-to-get-pdf.html

*( Side-note, my node.js version of the same code is at https://glitch.com/~ultra-sloop )*

### From this URL :

https://alphaindigo.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B1F4C6E80-0A55-4717-8D8D-19382F8E3C69%7D&file=Buddies.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true

### I generate this one.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYWluZGlnby5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86eDovci9fbGF5b3V0cy8xNS9Eb2MuYXNweD9zb3VyY2Vkb2M9JTdCMUY0QzZFODAtMEE1NS00NzE3LThEOEQtMTkzODJGOEUzQzY5JTdE/driveitem

When I run this in Graph Explorer as a test, it gives me the details of the driveItem, like this :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#shares('u%21aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYWluZGlnby5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86eDovci9fbGF5b3V0cy8xNS9Eb2MuYXNweD9zb3VyY2Vkb2M9JTdCMUY0QzZFODAtMEE1NS00NzE3LThEOEQtMTkzODJGOEUzQzY5JTdE')/driveItem/$entity",
    "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://alphaindigo.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=1f4c6e80-0a55-4717-8d8d-19382f8e3c69&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.L2t4YmRDQlpwS2dGMjIvdmxoVFA5ZXA0Qyt0b3VWWE9rb0h1UTJzcFVHRT0&ApiVersion=2.0",
    "createdDateTime": "2019-05-05T04:52:56Z",
    "eTag": "\"{1F4C6E80-0A55-4717-8D8D-19382F8E3C69},688\"",
    "id": "01FQPFGAEANZGB6VIKC5DY3DIZHAXY4PDJ",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-06-29T02:24:23Z",
    "name": "Buddies.xlsx",
    "webUrl": "https://alphaindigo.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B1F4C6E80-0A55-4717-8D8D-19382F8E3C69%7D&file=Buddies.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true",
    "cTag": "\"c:{1F4C6E80-0A55-4717-8D8D-19382F8E3C69},690\"",
    "size": 31938,
    "createdBy": {
    etc etc...
```

but when i attach /workbook/worksheet/file-name to the end

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYWluZGlnby5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86eDovci9fbGF5b3V0cy8xNS9Eb2MuYXNweD9zb3VyY2Vkb2M9JTdCMUY0QzZFODAtMEE1NS00NzE3LThEOEQtMTkzODJGOEUzQzY5JTdE/driveitem/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A1:D4')

I get this error :

```
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to find target address",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "5bea4b7f-91d9-4ba6-a26f-7964a4122a0a",
            "date": "2019-07-12T00:36:16"
        }
    }
}
```

If I step back from there, dropping the worksheet name and range using this :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYWluZGlnby5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86eDovci9fbGF5b3V0cy8xNS9Eb2MuYXNweD9zb3VyY2Vkb2M9JTdCMUY0QzZFODAtMEE1NS00NzE3LThEOEQtMTkzODJGOEUzQzY5JTdE/driveitem/workbook

I get the same error

A similar issue is already listed, answered at
 [Pulling Excel.xlsx workbook from Sharepoint site using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618008/pulling-excel-xlsx-workbook-from-sharepoint-site-using-microsoft-graph-api?newreg=671c05f723564fe6aea45d659e7357f4)

but as I already have a driveItem rather than a listItem it does not answer my issue.

Comment: Upvote so maybe someday an answer will appear. I am also struggling with this and the documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

A workaournd:

```
json_response = GET("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly9hbHBoYWluZGlnby5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86eDovci9fbGF5b3V0cy8xNS9Eb2MuYXNweD9zb3VyY2Vkb2M9JTdCMUY0QzZFODAtMEE1NS00NzE3LThEOEQtMTkzODJGOEUzQzY5JTdE/driveitem") 
drive_item = json_response["id"]
drive = json_response["parentReference"]["driveId"]
print(GET("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive}/items/{drive_item}/workbook"))
```