# Cannot find workbook relationship in a shareddriveitem/driveitem resource with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: excel, api, microsoft-graph-api

Using Microsoft Graph API I am able to get the workbook resource from a driveitem that is stored on my business OneDrive via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/`.

However, if another user shares the workbook to the organisation and I access it via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{EncodedSharingURL}/driveitem/`, I am not able to get the workbook resouce.

The response when trying to access the workbook of the shared driveitem is as follows:

```
"message": "Unable to find target address"
```

The JSON returned by the driveitem looks very similar in both cases. How is it different?

Comment: I am also struggling to figure this out

Comment: Great to know that, over 1 year later, this is still a mystery and Microsoft still hasn't updated their documentation on this.

Comment: I stumbled across the same issue. It does not resolve my own issue, but it seems like we are still able to fetch the full content of the file following this link: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{EncodedSharingURL}/driveitem/content`

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71109776/7448794

Answer (score 0):

For direct access to file you need drive ID and file ID which contains in [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{EncodedSharingURL}/driveitem/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/%7BEncodedSharingURL%7D/driveitem/) response:

driveID = driveitem.ParentReference.DriveId

fileID = driveitem.ParentReference.Id

Use it like this:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives(driveID)/items(fileID)/workbook/worksheets

Here it is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks

Comment: We discourage "link-only answers" here because when the links die your answer becomes worthless. Please copy whatever information from those links is relative to solving this exact problem. I generally leave the link to the source material at the bottom.