# Working with Sharepoint Online Excel files in Graph API

Tags: excel, api, sharepoint, graph

I got quite far following the hints from [Pulling Excel.xlsx workbook from Sharepoint site using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618008/pulling-excel-xlsx-workbook-from-sharepoint-site-using-microsoft-graph-api) but now I am stuck and would appreciate some help.

I want to call the Graph API Excel endpoint from a Power Automate flow and first I am testing things in the Graph Explorer but cannot get beyond a point.

What works (and confirms that the file's "mimeType" is "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenantid>.sharepoint.com:/sites/<siteid>:/lists/<listid>/items/19/driveitem
```

But when I try this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenantid>.sharepoint.com:/sites/<siteid>:/lists/<listid>/items/19/driveitem/workbook
```

... it generates error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "The parameter name path is not valid.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-10-22T08:04:16",
        "request-id": "aad38960-538d-4a5b-b3c6-097d19f07b09",
        "client-request-id": "a029dea8-f9f9-9a04-d4a3-7901be8d1eca"
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks!
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please have a try below endpoint?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteid>/lists/<listid>/items/8253/driveitem/workbook/worksheets
```

Below is my test:

[image]